# How can i prevent concurrent execution of SQL Server stored procedure with EF?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6 Database.SqlQuery statement to execute stored procedure. I want to prevent two users from executing the same stored procedure concurrently.

Comment: How can I  use critical section?

Comment: Critical Section is the wrong terminology, however take a look at this https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3202/prevent-multiple-users-from-running-the-same-sql-server-stored-procedure-at-the-same-time/

Comment: Is this code part of web service or part of win application?
if this is part of web service, you can lock this code to be sure stored procedure not run concurrently.

Comment: SQL Server has a built-in locking mechanism which is called transactions. You should select a proper `isolation level` for it. That's all! https://www.dotnettips.info/post/1761

Comment: That's a weird way to pass parameters, btw.

Comment: Thanks for your helps I don't have access to Stored Procedures.

Answer (score 1):

The below code will work correctly if all clients for calling stored procedures just call `ExecuteStoredProcedure` web service:

```
private Object thisLock = new Object(); 
public List<TResult> ExecuteStoredProcedure<TResult>(string storedProcedureName, object parameters) where TResult : new()
{
    lock (thisLock)  
    {  
        Type type = typeof(TResult);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append($"EXEC {storedProcedureName}");

        if (parameters == null)
            parameters = new { };

        var properties = parameters.GetType().GetProperties();
        object[] values = new object[properties.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append("@");
            sb.Append(properties[i].Name);
            sb.Append("=");
            sb.Append("@p");
            sb.Append(i);

            if (i < properties.Length - 1)
            {
                sb.Append(",");
            }

            values[i] = properties[i].GetValue(parameters);
        }

        if (type == typeof(ActionModel) || type.BaseType == typeof(ActionModel))
        {
            sb.AppendLine("");
            sb.AppendLine("WITH RESULT SETS ((IsValid BIT NULL,Id BIGINT NULL,Message NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL));");
        }

        return Database.SqlQuery<TResult>(sb.ToString(), values).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for both sync and async version

```
    private static readonly SemaphoreLocker _semaphoreLocker = new SemaphoreLocker();
    public async Task<List<TResult>> ExecuteStoredProcedureWithLockAsync<TResult>(string storedProcedureName, object parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken) where TResult : new()
    {
        List<TResult> result = new List<TResult>();
        await _semaphoreLocker.LockAsync(async () =>
        {
            result = await ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<TResult>(storedProcedureName, parameters, cancellationToken);
        }, cancellationToken);
        return result;
    }
    private Object _locker = new Object();
    public List<TResult> ExecuteStoredProcedureWithLock<TResult>(string storedProcedureName, object parameters) where TResult : new()
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            return ExecuteStoredProcedure<TResult>(storedProcedureName, parameters);
        }
    }

private class SemaphoreLocker
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    public async Task LockAsync(Func<Task> worker, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        try
        {
            await worker();
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with two ways:

1) If you want to lock just special Stored Procedure, you can use a dictionary like below:

```
static Dictionary<string, object> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
public List<TResult> ExecuteStoredProcedureWithLock<TResult>(string storedProcedureName, object parameters) where TResult : new()
{
    lock (_dictionary)
    {
        if (_dictionary.ContainsKey(storedProcedureName) == false)
        {
            _dictionary.Add(storedProcedureName, new object());
        }
    }

    lock (_dictionary[storedProcedureName])
    {
        return ExecuteStoredProcedure<TResult>(storedProcedureName, parameters);
    }
}

public async Task<List<TResult>> ExecuteStoredProcedureWithLockAsync<TResult>(string storedProcedureName, object parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken) where TResult : new()
{
    lock (_dic)
    {
        if (_dic.ContainsKey(storedProcedureName) == false)
        {
            _dic.Add(storedProcedureName, new object());
        }
    }
    List<TResult> result = new List<TResult>();
    Monitor.Enter(_dic[storedProcedureName]);
    try
    {
        result = await ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<TResult>(storedProcedureName, parameters, cancellationToken);
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(_dic[storedProcedureName]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

2) And also you can make sure that each stored procedure is executed once.Add the code below to start of the stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @ObjectId INT = OBJECT_ID('[' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID) + '].[' + OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) + ']')

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM  sys.sysprocesses as P 
              CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(P.sql_handle) T
        WHERE T.objectid = @ObjectId) = 1
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'SOMETHING'
    END
```

Comment: Great solution, simple and elegant.